# how can I print each indexed elements of 2D array individually in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to solve this problem.

Suppose I have,

```
$arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

I need the out put like:

> 1 2 3
>   4 5 6
>   7 8 9

Comment: Is this homework question?

Comment: no it is not. I practicing to learn.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, you should try to produce and include in your question a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems like you're in need of a tutorial on looping and printing. Stackoverflow isn't intended to be a source of code when you've put in zero effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you could have a nested loop. At the end of the each outer iteration you can print a newline.

```
<?php

$arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

foreach($arr as $list) {
   foreach($list as $element) {
     echo $element . ' ';
   }
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: But it showing me " PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion " on line 3.

Comment: @SimuSultana you can run the code yourself here: http://ideone.com/JA1VzA